# I want to use multiple database in prisma orm

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am not able to use multiple database in same application . How can we use multiple data sources.
Can we generate multiple "schema.prisma" for different database connections.

Comment: A little late to the party, but this article helped me a great deal setting up multiple database sources in prisma https://zach.codes/multiple-prisma-clients-one-app/

Answer (score 27):

You actually can with a workaround as specified [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2443#issuecomment-630679118). Create two different `schema.prisma` in separate folders and initialise `PrismaClient` for each `schema.prisma` that will point to the specific database.

Comment: Tested and working in the same folder, separate files:
  /prisma/schema1.prisma
  adding the "output: "./generated/client1"  parameter to the client

 and /prisma/schema2.prisma  
  adding the "output: "./generated/client2"  parameter to the client

When generate need to use --schema parameter like this:

     npx prisma generate --schema prisma/schema2.prisma

Tested with mysql 8, prisma 5.3.1 and  next 13.4.19

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible right now, see https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2443

Comment: In this issue you can find the following solution, in my case, this was very useful: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2443#issuecomment-630679118

Comment: @Gaalvarez that's the exact link from the top answer here.  OP should be accepting that - it's the best approach currently.

Answer (score 0):

[Video reference from codeGrepper](https://www.grepper.com/answers/685026/connect+with+multiple+database+prisma+stackoverflow?ucard=1)
generate two prisma schema  one by default scehma.prisma and another accoring to your will
2) in second scehema generate extra output path where prisma client will store
//prisma/retspy.prisma

```
 generator client {
        provider = "prisma-client-js"
        output   = "client/retspy"
    }

datasource db {
    provider = "mysql"
    url      = env("RETSPY_DATABASE_URL")
}
```

3)Generate client

```
import { PrismaClient as NcomDBPrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { PrismaClient as RetspyPrismaClient } from '../../prisma/client/retspy';

declare global {
  var ncomDBPrisma: NcomDBPrismaClient | undefined;
  var retspyPrisma: RetspyPrismaClient | undefined;
}   

const ncomDBClient = globalThis.ncomDBPrisma || new NcomDBPrismaClient();
const retspyClient = globalThis.retspyPrisma || new RetspyPrismaClient();

// Next.js hot reloading can cause issues with Prisma, so we store the clients globally.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  globalThis.ncomDBPrisma = ncomDBClient;
  globalThis.retspyPrisma = retspyClient;
}

export { ncomDBClient, retspyClient };
export default ncomDBClient;
```

//use both client according to will

```
import { retspyClient } from "@/app/libs/prismadb";
 const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await retspyClient.property_for_sale.findFirst({
        where: {
          state_or_province: {
            contains: "Albert",
          },
        },
      });
      // console.log(data);
      return data; // Return the fetched data
    } catch (err) {[enter link description here][1]
      console.log(err);
      return null; // Return null if there's an error
    }
  };
```